# CheckBox column in a JTable

Tags: python

Does anyone know how to add checkboxes to  JTable column in Python?

I need to add a checkbox column to my table. I have already created a table using swing library: DefaultTableModel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this in Jython or Python? I only know of JTable and swing library used in Jython.

Comment: It is in Python using Swing library and Java classes.

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to import libraries from a programming language to another.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no solution in this regard. I tried to use some java methods but with no results.
For example, I used `Boolean(0)` and `Boolean(1)` but both are recognized as `True` `False` values to be inserted in the table.

To select the lines I suggest you to use `ctrl + click` (Windows) or `cmd + click` (MacOS) and then use this piece of code:

```
i = 0
rowsToPrune = table.getSelectedRows()
while i < len(rowsToPrune):
   tableModel.removeRow(rowsToPrune[i] - i)
   i += 1
```

I often used this piece of code and it always went well, even for users!